# Failed to change password with UserManager.RemovePassword() and UserManager.AddPassword() in Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I use the following code to change a user's password:

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
var user = userManager.FindByName(currentUser.LoginName); // currentUser is the currently logged in user
IdentityResult result1 = userManager.RemovePassword(user.Id);
IdentityResult result2 = userManager.AddPassword(user.Id, txtPassword1.Text);
```

It works last year. But this year when I run it, it doesn't work (exactly the same code). When it runs to this statement:

```
IdentityResult result1 = userManager.RemovePassword(user.Id);
```

it gives the following exception:

```
{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PasswordHash', table 'xxx.dbo.AspNetUsers'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.The statement has been terminated."}
```

I debugged into into, right before that statement,

```
user.PasswordHash = 'AAdcuoWRRXqfkB+vWpemPCkFNgWRGGe2tXyeJHy21S8qYYfAo9wJbfqtkog+lk2dZg=='
```

but after this statement, `user.PasswordHash` becomes `null`

I am really confused. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want change user password use this code instead:

```
var validPass= await userManager.PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync(txtPassword1.Text);
if(validPass.Succeeded)
{
    var user = userManager.FindByName(currentUser.LoginName);
    user.PasswordHash = userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(txtPassword1.Text);
    var res= userManager.Update(user);
    if(res.Succeeded)
    {
        // change password has been succeeded
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your user's password you can try two kinds of approach.
One approach can be using "RemovePassword" and "AddPassword" as below:

```
                 string pwd = txtpwd.Text.Trim();
                var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
                var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
                string userName = UserName.Text;
                var user = userManager.FindByName(userName);
                if (user.PasswordHash != null)
                {
                    userManager.RemovePassword(user.Id);
                }

                userManager.AddPassword(user.Id, pwd);
```

Another approach is using "ChangePassword" as below:

```
            var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
            var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
           // var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = UserName.Text };
            if (UserName.Text != null && txtcurpwd != null && txtNewpwd != null)
            {
                string username = UserName.Text;
                var user = userManager.FindByName(username);
                IdentityResult result = userManager.ChangePassword(user.Id, txtcurpwd.Text, txtNewpwd.Text);

                if (result.Succeeded)

                    lblErrorMsg.Text = "password changed successfully for the user : " + username;
                else
                    lblErrorMsg.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();


            }
            else
                lblErrorMsg.Text = "Details missing ";
        }
```